# Java need help to close Stream

Tags: java, xml, dom, io, stream

I got a DOM parser in my DOM parser, and it seems to left unclosed `Stream`s after writing to the `XML` file.

My program creates a file, and call this code (look below) to write `xml-nodes` to the file. My program also contains a "delete" file function, which doesn't works because there are some Streams unclosed Streams, so deleting file returns false.

When I rerun the program, I am able to delete the file.. But every time I create a new, or edit in an existing file inside the program, the program seems to left some opened `Stream`s.

This following code is the part that left an unclosed `Stream`. I tried to somehow close the `Streamresult`, but there's no method to close it.

```
public void rewriteXML(){
try{

        DocumentBuilderFactory song = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder songBuilder = song.newDocumentBuilder();

            Document doc = songBuilder.newDocument();
            Element playlist = doc.createElement("playlist");
            doc.appendChild(playlist);

            TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer tr = tf.newTransformer();
            tr.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
            DOMSource dom = new DOMSource(doc);
            StreamResult sr = new StreamResult(new FileOutputStream(fileName,false));

            tr.transform(dom, sr);

            System.out.println("done");

        }catch(ParserConfigurationException pce){
            pce.printStackTrace();
        }catch(TransformerException fce){
            fce.printStackTrace();
        }catch(IOException ie){
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I need some way to either close the `Stream`, or a way to bug fix for open `Stream`s, because I am not really sure what `Stream` is unclosed.

Comment: You could declare your FileOutputStream as a variable named `out`, and call `out.close()` when you're done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FileOutputStream` is a `Stream`. `StreamResult` is not a `Stream`, but it *contains one*. The trick is to find it and then close it.

`sr.getOutputStream().close()`

Michael Kay (comments) pointed out that `StreamResult` leaves any `Stream` that is passed to it open. If you did not know this and wanted to be safe, it might be worth noting that most streams in Java do not throw an exception if you attempt to close them twice. If you aren't sure, close it again.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! I was aware of that StreamResult wasnt a Stream, but i thought if a StreamResult contained a Stream, Java would apply methods to to the Stream through StreamResult.. Well nothing is that easy! Thanks :-)!

Comment: The usual convention is that the code that created the stream is responsible for closing it. It's considered bad manners to close a stream that you didn't create, even if you have read to the end of it (though it's sometimes necessary in cases where the creator doesn't get the chance). But in this case, you created the stream so it's your job to close it.

Comment: @MichaelKay It's not super obvious to anyone really that simply passing a `Stream` to `StreamResult` opens the stream. I found your comment in 2009 regarding this, and it looks like nothing was done about it. https://java.net/projects/jaxp/lists/eg/archive/2009-03/message/0

Answer (score 2):

Better yet, don't create the stream yourself; let the `StreamResult` handle opening and closing:

```
StreamResult sr = new StreamResult(new File(fileName));
```